# Branch of the cube root

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)=z^{1/3}$ be the branch of the cube root whose domain of definition is given by $0<\theta<2\pi$, $z\neq 0$ (i.e. the branch cut is along the ray $\theta=0$.) Find $f(-i)$.

Could someone please help me understand the question? I'm not too clear on "branches" and "branch cuts".

Answer (score 3):

When $\theta \in [0,2 \pi]$, $-i=e^{i 3 \pi/2}$.  Thus,

$$f(-i) = \left ( e^{i 3 \pi/2} \right )^{1/3}  = e^{i \pi/2} = i$$

If the branch cut were along the negative real axis, then $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$ and $-i = e^{-i \pi/2}$ so that $f(-i) = e^{-i \pi/6}$.